# Application Logic (Proper place for Authentication/Authorization)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, logic, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a CMS like application using MVC 3 (RC2) and I am in crossroads at this point. I am unable to convince myself if my proposed approach is appropriate or not. I guess it is because I am aware that I am trying to cut some corners which will cost me heavily later down the line.

I will get right down to describing my problem:

1) I have a resource (lets call it A) which has to be made editable.

2) I have a custom permission system implemented which has 2 (of many) permissions:

- Can Edit Own Resource
- Can Edit Other Resource

3) Creator of resource A is free to edit it if they have 'Can Edit Own Resource' permission.

4) A separate user can only edit A if they have permission 'Can Edit Other Resource'

Now that the requirement is described, let me tell you my approach so far:

1) I have a controller called 'ResourceController'

2) I have a action called 'Edit'

3) The action has a attribute on it: [CustomerAuthorize(Perm.CanEditOwnResource, Perm.CanEditOtherResource, Any = true)]

4) I have a service class which takes care of domain validation.

So a user get call the action method if they have either the 'Can Edit Own Resource' or 'Can Edit Other Resource' permission.

How do I decide (and where should this decision be made) on whether the user has the right permission or not (depending on whether they own the resource?) Should it be in the controller action, in the resource service class, in a separate service class?

Waiting to hear different views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the nature of MVC, you will want to have your authentication checks at a variety of points.

For one, you'll need to be able to display visual cues on the UI (i.e. show the edit button or not show it), so the logic will have to be made available to your Views.

Of course, that's only for UI purposes.  You'll want authentication/authorization on your controller actions as well, just in case someone goes around your UI to access it.

Finally, the most secure place to authenticate and authorize an action is right before you perform it.  If you have a handler, for example, I would place some authorization logic there.  You want to make sure that no one can write around your security logic by calling the service from somewhere else, and not knowing that there were restrictions on that service. This helps make the security options more granular as well.

Comment: But isnt that duplication of logic? Having the same checks repeated multiple times? But I understand your concern. I wonder if I could see some OSS projects to learn the pattern.

Comment: @KiD0M4N: There are some scenarios where repeating some logic is much easier (including long term maintenance considerations) than not repeating it.  That is, sometimes technological constraints or existing design decisions make it unreasonably difficult to pursue totally pure "do-not-repeat-yourself".

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach it is to have 2 actions, instead only "Edit", you have "EditOwnResource" and "EditOtherResource". You can then place a single permission on each of these.

Then if you are using the MVVM pattern you can bind the availability of these actions to wether it is an ownResource or otherResource. The setting of these values is done in the view model.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC. So the MVVM bits don't apply. But I will think about having two separate front actions. But it probably won't be possible in my particular case